# bjobs output not being stored properly in variable

Tags: bash, csh

So, I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    bjobs_output=$(bjobs)
    echo HELLO
    echo $bjobs_output
    echo WORLD
    sleep 1
done
```

I am running the command in a cshell because bjobs does not work in the bourne shell

And this results in the following output:

```
No unfinished job found
HELLO

WORLD
```

However, I want to check that all the bjobs are complete by checking the string of the variable but it is not storing properly. For example

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    bjobs_output=$(echo WHOLE)
    echo HELLO
    echo $bjobs_output
    echo WORLD
    sleep 1
done
```

Gives

```
HELLO
WHOLE
WORLD
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Likely `No unfinished job found` is being written to the standard error stream, rather than to the standard output stream

Comment: This makes alot of sense, I haven't tried it out but I realised that bjobs has a stdout nil string unless there is an unfinished job, so I used that instead

Comment: Why do you need to store the output in a variable at all? Can't you just call `bjobs` at the correct place in the code from the start? Unrelated to your actual issue: You also need to quote the expansion of the `bjobs_output` variable when you use it with e.g. `echo`. You also mentioned `csh`, but I see nothing relating to this in your code.